# Do blue teams plant CTF like canaries across infrastructure?

Tags: honeypot

I am working on a SaaS application that handles sensitive data. I had the idea of planting various canaries across our application / infrastructure to get early warnings of people being a bit too much interested in our work.

The idea is to plant various CTF like "challenges" with various difficulty that would allow us to get an idea of the skill levels of a potential threat actor.

Here are some of the *challenges* I was thinking of by increasing order of complexity:

- Hidden folder with public but no-so-easy to guess URL
- zip-bomb with fake DB dump
- Expose a fake command injection form in our app and listen for every attempts
- Regular SSH honeypot behind the DMZ
- Document planted with a beacon in our file server
- Plant a binary somewhere with a custom hidden backdoor
- AWS credz planted in the git repo with an associated canary

Is this a really bad idea? Could this backfire to us?

Comment: Do you want to entertain the attackers or identify them to block them? What's your ultimate goal? What does knowing the skill level tell you? How would that affect your response?

Answer (score 4):

What you have described is a medium- or high-interaction honeypot, honeyusers, and honeyrecords. The technique has been around for many years.

Honeypots within the perimeter of your network can be very useful, but should be low-interaction honeypots. Even a server with a SSH service running without any valid logins can be a useful honeypot. Any login attempts are immediately suspicious.

High-interaction honeypots are used outside of the perimeter to learn how attackers are approaching your assets and to gather info in order to raise specific defenses.

Anything you place in the hands of an attacker will be used against you. So you need to protect yourself from your own attempts to track an attacker.

If you do some reading on honeypots and other deception technologies, you will get a sense for what is seen as best practice.